# Foundation Columns in the same row appearing in same row

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

I have two divs large-6 columns in the same row, but they appear beneath each other.

```
<div class="row" style="height:100%;">
  <div class="large-6 cloumns show-for-large-up" style="height:inherit;">
    <!-- Some Content -->
  </div>
  <div class="large-6 cloumns show-for-large-up" style="height:inherit;">
    <!-- Some Content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried removing the 100% height etc, but it hasn't fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to see your css for this html, but you likely need to add a float and width to the inner divs for them to appear side by side. Try adding `float:left; width:50%;` to `.large-6`

Comment: '.large-6' has 'width:50%;' and '.columns' has 'float:left;'

Comment: `.columns` is spelled incorrectly above... Is that it? I'm not sure what's wrong without seeing all the code. That should work.

Comment: No problem, we've all been there.